# Change Mac Keyboard Identifier after keyboard replacement

Tags: mac, keyboard

I replaced my MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013) keyboard. The U.S keyboard layout is mapped incorrectly now. It seems to be a problem with the keyboard identifier ID (maybe its Bundle ID). It looks like to be Japanese now but I need to change it back to english (I can't achieve this by changing input source and keyboard layout).

Comment: This sounds like a "keyboard type" problem, but you should tell us why you think it is mapped like JIS instead of ANSI.  See if this note helps:  http://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2009/12/fixing-keyboard-type-problems.html

Comment: Yes it's keyboard type problem but i can't figure out how solve this.
My keyboard looks like this https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0810/3669/files/mac-us-english-keyboard_1024x1024.png?1871373995114389746 but mac thinks it's looks like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/oz2xyy2vd0v3qe0/Screenshot%202016-02-13%2015.17.19.png?dl=0

Comment: I tried this link http://m10lmac.blogspot.lt/2009/12/fixing-keyboard-type-problems.html but it's not helped

Comment: So you tried all the suggestions including PMU reset, running keyboard setup assistant from terminal, trashing the keyboardtype.plist?

Comment: Yes i tried and nothing helped

Comment: Maybe there is some file which i can edit for change type?

Comment: I think it would logically be the keyboardtype.plist.  Your machine thinks you have a JIS keyboard and it should be ANSI instead.

Comment: Yes and i thought that way. But in this file i can't identify where can be keyboard type.

Comment: None of the fixes in the linked site worked for me, and the Karabiner app no longer has the screen shown in the selected answer, nor any way that I could see to re-map tilde and section. When I run the Keyboard setup app, it doesn't know what type of keyboard I have, and I select ANSI at the end. It still behaves like it has an ISO keyboard. On a lark, I selected ISO, and now it behaves like an ANSI keyboard.

Comment: @MidnightJava, for me works with Karabiner-elements https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Element

Comment: @napalias: what version of Karabiner-Elements are you using? I don't even see the Change Key tab at the top like you have in your selected answer. It has different tabs and buttons, and nothing (that I've found) which lets me configure keyboard layout or specify keyboard type.

Comment: @MidnightJava i use 11.1.0 version. This karabiner version which is in my screenshot was stopped to work when next  macos update was released. For this reason, i was forced to use Karabiner-elements (this is separate download then karabiner, and looks differently).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't find way how do without side app. But i solved with "Karabiner"

[image]

Comment: Great info, thanks!  This is a rare problem but hard to solve when it occurs.

Comment: just installed this and fixed my problem. Black magic!

Comment: https://github.com/pqrs-org/Karabiner-Elements

Answer (score 2):

The following [Karabiner](https://github.com/pqrs-org/Karabiner-Elements) config works for me:

[image: config]

Answer (score 1):

It works for me but with different steps due to the recent version of Karabiner-Elements go to:

- Virtual keyboard > Country code: 0
  I choose ISO (according to my keyboard sort)

Then:

- **Devices** > Disable **Modify Events** in Apple's built-in keyboard
  This prevents the modification of the keyboard layout

You will need to log out in order to apply the changes (for all the users).